# What is the practical use of class decorations in Python?

Tags: python, decorator

In Python 2.6, [PEP 3129](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) introduced "class decorators" to Python compliment function decorators already present in the language. I cannot see when or where something like this might be used practically, and I am interested in knowing if there is an improvement in performance by using class decorators over not using them to achieve the same result.

Comment: I would appreciate input as to why this question is being downvoted. I do not understand how this could be interpreted as being highly opinion-based.

Comment: It's a perfectly good question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class decorators are function that take class objects as input and change the object that binds to the name of the input class to the output of the function (usually you want to return the same class). They are an alternative to inheritance and metaclasses to customize the class behavior and are different in that they act after the class has been fully created, instead of affecting the class creation process. Another difference is that class decorators are not inherited which could be advantageous over metaclasses in some situations.

```
def register_handlers(cls):
    token = 'handle_'
    cls.handler_dict = {k[len(token):] : getattr(cls,k) for k in dir(cls) if k.startswith(token)}
    return cls

@register_handlers
class Handler:
    def handle_input(self):
        pass

    def handle_output(self):
        pass

    def handle_error(self):
        pass
```

Additionally it is not required that a class decorator modifies the class at all, it could just return it and e.g. register it somewhere:

```
game_objects = {}

def register_object(cls):
    game_objects[cls.__name__] = cls
    return cls

@register_object
class Chair:
    pass

@register_object
class Car:
    pass
```

Comment: In your registering example, what would be the benefit of placing the `register_object` as a decorator instead of just calling the function with parameter `self` inside an `__init__` function inside the classes?

Comment: The init method applies to an instance, wheres this applies to the class itself. You would have to use the `__new__` method of the metaclass for a similar behavior.

Comment: Oh so the decorator is called on the class itself and not on any instances of the class that get created?

Comment: Yes, the decorator is identical to `cls = decorator(cls)`

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple uses of class decorators. One case which made sense to me is registering a class in a publisher-subscriber system, e.g. plugins or events, something like:

```
@register
class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    pass
or

@recieves_notifications
class Console:
    def print(self, text):
        ...
```

another use could be for example when writing unit tests having the @unittest.skipIf and @unittest.skipUnless can be used on either individual methods or on an entire unittest.TestCase class definition. This makes for writing tests for platform specific problems so much easier.

```
Example from asyncio/test_selectors

# Some platforms don't define the select.kqueue object for these tests.
# On those platforms, this entire grouping of tests will be skipped.

@unittest.skipUnless(hasattr(selectors, 'KqueueSelector'),
                 "Test needs selectors.KqueueSelector)")
class KqueueSelectorTestCase(BaseSelectorTestCase, ScalableSelectorMixIn):
...
```

Comment: Although this adequately explains function decorators, I am talking about class decorators.

Comment: check now :) the answer